# jQuery ui datepicker doesn't disappear on clicking outside on IOS

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have added jquery datepicker in my PHP site. The datepicker doesn't disappear on clicking outside on IOS. It works fine on desktop. Have anybody faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your datepickers have the class hasDatepicker, so try this:

```
$(".hasDatepicker").blur(function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });
```

it's relatively short compared to alternate ways I thought of.

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
   var ele = $(e.toElement); 
   if (!ele.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-icon") && !$(ele).parent().parents(".ui-datepicker").length)
   $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide"); 
});
```

the problem i encountered was being able to tell when the span icon was clicked, it wasnt really wanting to cooperate, thus the extra has class checks

Comment: I have tried this, but this makes issues. I have multiple datepicker fields in the same page.

Comment: Multiple datepicker doesn't make any issue if you are using class instead of id

Comment: I have tried the second code you have given again. But the issue still persists on iOs. The datepicker doesn't disappear when I tap/touch on other places (like labels, vacant spaces etc.). When I click on other fields, it  disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution, probably not the best but it works for me. Feedback welcome

CSS:

```
#backdrop {visibility:hidden;z-index: 5;position:fixed;background-color:#000;height:100%;width:100%;top:0px;left:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

adjust `z-index` to appropriate value ensuring that #backdrop (when not hidden) is in front of other elements, and Datepicker is highest in stack order

JQuery:

```
$jq('#elementid').datepicker({
            beforeShow: function(){
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) && !window.MSStream) {
                   if ($('backdrop') == null) {
                        var screen = new Element('div', {'id': 'backdrop'});
                        document.body.appendChild(screen);
                   }
                   Event.observe('backdrop', 'click', function() {
                        $jq("$jq('#elementid').").datepicker("hide");
                   });
                   $jq('#backdrop').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity': '0'}); //adjust visible opacity if required
            },
            onClose: function(){
                if ($('backdrop') != null) {
                        $jq('#backdrop').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': '0'});
                   }
            }
});
```